# Realtime data replication from DataBase to front end in java based web application

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, ajax, riak

I am building a customer support web application (java based) where I need to show all "Customer Representative(CR)" status (available, busy, away in phone) in the front-end.

If CR terminates the call after talking to someone, status will get updated in my database. At the same time, it should get reflected in front-end as well.

1. Ajax may be one option to keep on polling Database for CR status.

Is there any other approach available to make this work?

Comment: I think you should take a look to _websocket_ protocol

Comment: I gone through websocket sample example(url below). Which explained about front-end to server communication without refresh page. But in my case , i need to get data from dataBase whenever gets updated. (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html#)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine, usually. From your comment, it seems that you are using Oracle, which (depending on the edition) may have the ability to call a web service. So you can create a trigger in the DB, that trigger will fire back in your app ...

Comment: how about this one http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/blog/push-notification-server-streaming-on-a-mysql-database/